# C++ Template names: compilation error in Visual Studio, works fine in gcc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The following code fails to compile using Visual Studio Express 2012:

```
template< int d >
class MyVector
{
public:
    typedef double X;
};

class Base
{
public:
    int d;
    int m() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template<int d>
class Derived1 : Base
{
    typedef typename MyVector<d>::X X;
};

template<int m>
class Derived2 : Base
{
    typedef typename MyVector<m>::X X;
};
```

I get the "error C2327: 'Base::d' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator" at Derived1 and the "error C2975: 'd' : invalid template argument for 'MyVector', expected compile-time constant expression" at Derived2.

Of course, it is easy to see that the problem are the template arguments names, that conflict with the Base member names. If I change the derived template names to

```
template<int ddd>
class Derived1 : Base
{
    typedef typename MyVector<ddd>::X X;
};

template<int mmm>
class Derived2 : Base
{
    typedef typename MyVector<mmm>::X X;
};
```

the code compiles fine.

However, the original code compiles without any problems in Linux, using gcc 4.6.4. So my question is: which compiler is right, according to the standard? I consider myself a newbie at this c++ template subtleties, but my instincts tend to prefer the gcc interpretation: after all, if Derived1 wished to access the Base member 'd' it would require the notation 'Base::d' or 'this->d', so I guess there should not be a name conflict in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Who's to blame?

`gcc 4.6.4` is relatively old, but nonetheless; it's wrong to accept the snippet.

<sup>**Edit**: prior to this edit it was stated that 4.6.4 was *"very old"*. I inaccurately thought it was released back in 2011, but it's actually from 13 Apr 2013.</sup>

---

#### What does the Standard say? ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))

> `14.6.1p9` **Locally declared names** `[temp.local]`
>
> > If the definition of a class template or in the definition of a member of such a template that appears outside of the template definition, for each base class which does not depend on a *template-parameter* (14.6.2), `[ Note: >> ]` if the name of the base class or the name of a member of the base class is the same as the name of a *template-parameter*, the base class name or member name hides the *template-parameter* name `[ << --end note ]`(3.3.10).

<sup>**Note**: The relevant, and semantically equivalent, wording for *C++03* can be found at `[temp.local]p7` in **14882:2003**.</sup>

The last sentence from the section quoted above says that if the name of a *template-parameter* is the same as a name found in a *non-dependent* base, the member-name will effectively hide the *template-parameter*.

The bug has been fixed in newer versions of `gcc`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But is gcc 4.6.4 really *very old*? I mean, it comes shipped with the most recent LTS version of Ubuntu! *sigh*: I'm feeling like a dinosaur (and an old one...)

Comment: @BrunoDamas see the last edit, I've removed the statement saying that it's "very old" after taking a look at the release notes of 4.6.4. Compared to the newest release of gcc (4.9.0, Apr 2014) it is however.. "Semi-old" `;-)`.

Comment: Too bad, that there is no warning for such name conflicts